# How can I read content (http response body) from a QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, response, qwebview, qnetworkreply

I'm using qt5.3 and I googled a lot before I post.

I want to read data from `QNetworkReply`. I have a `QWebView` and I also need the http response to be read by `QWebView` to display the webpage. What I need is just to log the web content or whatever response to http posts.

The problem is `QNetworkReply` is something that can only be read once.

1. If I call `readAll()` when I pick `readyRead()` signal, I will get the full data. But it will be cleared so `QWebView` displays nothing (it won't get any reply data).
2. Or if I pick `finished()` signal, since the data is already read by `QWebView` (or `QNetworkAccessManager`), I get nothing if I call `readAll()` here. Is there somewhere that `QNetworkReply`, or manager or any class, stores the data which I can still read?

In #1 I can get part of the data if I call `peek()`. This function does not clear the response data. But it won't work if the response body is big. The `QNetworkReply` is a sequential thing that I can neither know its data nor read further than buffered.

I have no idea of how to do with this.....

I just want to monitor and log the request and response body of any request made on my `QWebView` ...

Edit: note that my data to read from response is as large as 1MB so it won't be ok to peek the whole data without further reading.

Comment: Both your points 1 and 2 stem from your misunderstanding of how `QNetworkReply` should be used. In programming, there is no such thing as things that can only be read once. Either you buffer it or you don't; in which you end up losing the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own subclass of `QNetworkAccessManager` and override virtual function `createRequest`. Call base class implementation to get the response object and connect `readyRead` signal to some slot that will capture the data. In that slot call peek function to read data so that WebKit will get the data also :

```
class NetworkAccessManagerProxy : public QNetworkAccessManager {
Q_OBJECT

signals:

    void dataGot(QByteArray data);

public:
    NetworkAccessManagerProxy(QObject * parent = 0)
         : QNetworkAccessManager()
    {
    }

    virtual QNetworkReply* createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest& request, QIODevice *outgoingData)
    {
        reply = QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request, outgoingData);
        connect(this,SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readInternal()));
        return reply;
    }

private slots:

     void readInternal()
     {
        QByteArray data = reply->peek(reply->bytesAvailable());
        emit dataGot(data);
     }

private:

    QNetworkReply* reply;
};
```

After creating `QWebPage` object, call `setNetworkAccessManager` and pass a newly created instance of your subclass :

```
QWebPage * page = new QWebPage; 
page->setNetworkAccessManager(new NetworkAccessManagerProxy());
page->mainFrame()->load(url);

webView->setPage(page);
```

Comment: This works when reply data is small. My data to read is as large as 1MB and bytesAvailable() mostly returns some value around 10000 bytes.

Comment: I think the `connect` statement should be `connect(reply,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readInternal()))`.